# Stop VPN Disconnecting when going to Sleep

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, vpn

When the iPhone (4) goes to sleep, the VPN will disconnect.
Is there any way to disable this behavior as it's sometimes a bit annoying.

*I am jailbroken, and the server I'm connecting to is Windows Server 2008 R2 which I can edit settings on.*

Answer (score 1):

The VPN will disconnect because your WiFi disconnects.

Therefore you would have to...

- either reconnect your VPN connection when on 3G (How?)
- or enable your iPhone to keep connected to WiFi (requires jailbreak)

To keep WiFi on in sleep mode you need to install **KeepAwake** via Cydia.

See this [step-by-step guide](http://jaxov.com/2010/07/keep-your-wifi-on-iphone-sleep-mode/).

Comment: I don't use WiFi though, it has got a constant 3G Conection

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that sleeping an iPhone and staying connected to the network are incompatible goals. If you don't want to drop the VPN connection, you need to keep the device awake.

However, I found a [discussion on apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17283816#17283816) that states that plugged-in devices are able to maintain network connections while in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 things and now the VPN does not disconnect even while switching from wifi to 3G.

1. Install Cisco Anyconnect to connect to VPN network.
2. Install KeepAwake(from cydia) --Thanks, gentmatt

Now it's all fine, i can work from anywhere on my 3GS and VPN remains connected while on the move also.

Answer (score 0):

I turns on a music at background with volume turned off .. Put it on repeat, my brother turn auto lock to off on his iPod . To keep the VPN alive  , and VPN will not disconnect ... But may be there's a cydia tweak for tha

Answer (score 0):

This works for me iPhone 5 iso 6.1.4;

http://www.ehow.com/how_12133063_keep-vpn-alive-iphone.html#page=0

Comment: Please write down how it works because the URL might die in the future.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround that I found was on a jailbroken device, use activator and link unlocking device to a toggle to turn on VPN.  Therefor every time I unlock my device the VPN reconnects so I am happy :)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cultofmac.com/225244/apple-decides-not-to-kill-always-on-vpn-for-ios-devices/

hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Please do not only add link-answers without details as the links might die.